# Sencha CMD not copying resources folder

Tags: extjs, build

I am using SenchCMD 5.0.2.270 and Sencha Touch 2.4.0 and Cordova Android

Building an app with

```
sencha app build native
```

the resources from the app.json resources are not being copied:

```
"resources": [
    "resources",
    "resources/images",
    "resources/icons",
    "resources/startup"
],
```

The only resources in the final output is the css folder.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, did you ever find a solution to the problem?

Comment: I did find that manually copying the images to the folder and using sencha app emulater or run it did grab those along with the rest. But its odd and quite annoying to have to take such steps.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows machine. Works fine on Linux. Are you on windows too?

Comment: Yes, I am working on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is issue with the Sencha packaging of Android build folder, such that it is not copying the resources as expected, i was saw the issue marked [HERE](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?284099-sencha-app-build-and-resources-images)

Comment: The link only points out that the splash and icons are not copied inside cordova. But I am going for any files other the standard. Adding a new folder to the project and to the file, will not copy the content.